# jQuery AJAX GET SUCCESS firing too fast

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

My "success" response seems to be firing too fast, so I've been forced to go from this...

```
  $('.hs_cart button').click(function(){
    $.get($(this).attr('url'), {
      success: function(){
        refresh_mini_cart();
      }
    });
  });
```

to this...

```
  $('.hs_cart button').click(function(){
    $.get($(this).attr('url'), {
      success: function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
          refresh_mini_cart();
        }, 5000);
      }
    });
  });
```

I've also tried the following but am receiving a "404 not found"...

```
  $('.hs_cart button').click(function(){
    $.get({
      url: $(this).attr('url'),
      success: function(){
        refresh_mini_cart();
      }
    });
  });
```

What am I doing wrong where I'm having to insert a setTimeout??

This is the Woocommerce function I am attempting to fire...

```
  function refresh_mini_cart(){
    $.ajax($fragment_refresh).done(function(response){
      if(response.cart_hash.length !== 0)
        return true;
    });
  }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I don't think your syntax for `$.get()` is correct. [Docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Comment: @jack I've added another version of the code, but am receiving a 404 error.

Comment: your refresh_mini_cart() method shouldn't be getting called at the moment.

Comment: @dave The link doesn't answer my question as I'm already attempting to use the success callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplify your `$.get()` a bit. Try the below code.

```
$('.hs_cart button').click(function(){
    $.get($(this).attr('url'), function() {
        refresh_mini_cart();
    });
});
```

Your issue was that your syntax for `$.get()` wasn't correct.

Comment: THANK YOU!! Btw, why is it "this" was no longer the button?

Comment: @RyanPrentiss it should still be the button in that case.